# How to pass json data from one javascript function to another javascript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-4

JS + Jquery + Rails 4

1.) view.html.erb

```
<%= select_tag "schedule[id]", options_for_select(@travel_names), {:multiple => true, :onchange => "renderSchedules(#{raw @schedule_hash.to_json},#{raw @deals_hash.to_json});" } %>
```

@schedule_hash = instance,
 @deals_hash = instance
 , passing to the js function as json format.

2.) webapp.js

```
function renderSchedules(json_data, deals_hash){
   new_json_data = filterSchedule(json_data, deals_hash);
   //More Code
}

function filterSchedule(json_data, deals_hash) {
//More Code
 $('#active_fiters_blk').append('<a href="#" id="active_travel_filter" style="color:#F26F21;margin-right:3%;" value="'+operator_ids[i]+'" onclick="removeTravelFilter('+json_data+','+deals_hash+')">"Link"</a>');
// Here i am getting json_data = [object Object], deal_hash = [object, Object] on console , i need to pass json data to removeTravelFilter function
}

function removeTravelFilter(jd, dh){
  //Some COnditions
  renderSchedules(jd, dh);
  // From here also i need to pass json data to renderSchedule function.
}
```

Comment: did you get any errors?

Comment: Why are you using inline script???

Comment: No Error, But while passing json_data it is showing [object Object] on Console.

Comment: @A.Wolff i tried separate too same result. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have better to not use inline script:

```
function filterSchedule(json_data, deals_hash) {
    $('<a href="#" id="active_travel_filter" style="color:#F26F21;margin-right:3%;" value="' + operator_ids[i] + '">Link</a>').on('click', function () {
        removeTravelFilter(json_data, deals_hash);
    }).appendTo('#active_fiters_blk');
}
```

<strike>That's said, IDs must be unique on document context. Looks like your code is duplicating IDs.</strike>

Comment: No i have unique id, i removed suffix because i need to make code understandable to all.

Comment: This is not .appending to the div

Comment: If the DIV is `'#active_fiters_blk'` it should append the link. So any error in console? EDIT: i see, missing double quote, updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to stringify your `json_data` because it is an Object. The `toString`method on an Object returns the string `"[object Object]"`. You need to use:

```
onclick="removeTravelFilter('+JSON.stringify(json_data)+','+JSON.stringify(deals_hash)+')">
```

Comment: Actually i want inline script for each link but if i am giving this then construction of link is getting wrong ?

<a travels"}},{})"="" onclick="removeTravelFilter({" value="43" style="color:#F26F21;margin-right:3%;" href="#"